# Why is the file not being sent to server side?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, parsing, web

I have a simple file input like this:

```
 <input type="file" id="profilePhotoFileUpload" onchange="saveImage()">
```

then the `saveImage()` function looks like this:

```
function saveImage() {

    var fileUploadControl = $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0];

    if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {
      var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
      var name = "brand_logo"

      var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);

      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('image', parseFile); 

      console.log("dATA: " + JSON.stringify(formData))

      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("POST", "/about");
      request.send(formData);

    }

  }
```

On my server side, I have my post route like this:

```
app.post('/about', function(req, res){

console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(req.body))

});
```

It looks like the data is empty to begin with, on both client side and server side, it comes out to be empty data like so:

```
  {}
```

Comment: What is `Parse`?

Comment: I believe you need a middleware on the server side to parse the body of the request, something like body-parser or in your case I believe you need one that can handle multi-part form data, possibly https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Comment: @macdja38 I don't think that's the issue because on the client side when I log the formData, it is empty before it even sends to the server.